# How do I bind Find Next command to a keyboard shortcut for .page files in Eclipse?

Tags: apex, eclipse

For whatever reason, Find Next does not have a keyboard shortcut when editing .page files in Eclipse.  It is there for .cls files.

Is there a way to bind the Find Next command to a shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change shortcut in Eclipse ?

Open Windows->Preferences->General->Keys. Now you can use the filter to find your shortcut and change its binding.

Here is sample tutorial - http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key

Comment: I did.  Made no difference for the .page and .component files.

Comment: Ohhk, Let me try in System. I will get back

Comment: Actually, sorry, you are right...  I changed the binding to something else, then back to F3 and it worked!!! Thanks.